# Perl right way to write macros

Tags: perl

In order to simplify my program, I would like to write some macros that I can use in different subroutines.

Here's what I wrote:

```
my @m = ();
sub winit   { @m = (); }
sub w       { push @m, shift; }
sub wline   { push @m, ''; }
sub wheader { push @m, commentHeader(shift); }
sub walign  { push @m, alignMakeRule(shift); }
sub wflush  { join($/, @m); }

sub process {
    winit;

    w "some text";
    wline;

    wheader 'Architecture';   
    w getArchitecture();
    wline;

    say wflush;
}
```

Is there a better way or a smarter way to do what I want to do?

Comment: What so you mean with `macro`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use closure, or hash of closures if you find such approach useful,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

sub winit {
  my @m;
  return (
    w       => sub  { push @m, shift; },
    wline   => sub  { push @m, ''; },
    wheader => sub  { push @m, "commentHeader ". shift; },
    walign  => sub  { push @m, "alignMakeRule ". shift; },
    wflush  => sub  { join($/, @m); },
  );
}

sub process {
    my %w = winit();

    $w{w}->("some text");
    $w{wline}->();

    $w{wheader}->('Architecture');   
    $w{w}->("getArchitecture()");
    $w{wline}->();

    say $w{wflush}->();
}

process();
```

Comment: For three fewer lines, you could make a class. Why not do that instead? Then `$w{wline}->();` becomes `$w->wline();`

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood what you're trying to do, what I'd be thinking is to start looking at object oriented perl.

Objects are way of building  complex data structures, and 'building in' code to 'do things' to the data structure.

So you'd create an object (perl module):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package MyMacro;

sub new {
    my ($class) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    $self->{m} = ();
    bless( $self, $class );
}

sub flush {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return join( $/, @{ $self->{m} } );
}

sub addline {
    my ($self) = @_;
    push( @{$self -> {m}}, '' );
}

sub addtext {
    my ( $self, $text ) = @_;
    push ( @{$self -> {m}}, $text );
}

#etc. for your other functions

1;
```

And then 'drive' it with:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyMacro;

my $w = MyMacro->new();

$w->addtext("some text");
$w->addline();
$w->addtext("some text");

print $w ->flush;
```

This is pretty basic OOP, but you can do more advanced with `Moose`.